# MissingMethodException in unit test with HibernateTestMixin when using dynamic finder after upgrade to Grails 3.0.6

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

After upgrading a Grails 2.5.1 application to Grails 3.0.6 I am having troubles to get my unit tests working again.

I have a very simple domain class called `Team`.

```
class Team {

   String name
   String shortName
   String image = 'noimage.jpg'

   static constraints = {
       name nullable: false, maxSize: 30, unique: true
       shortName nullable: true, maxSize: 5
       image nullable: false, maxSize: 30
   }
}
```

and a unit test that does this

```
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
@Domain([Team])
class TeamSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        new Team(name: 'Hello', shortName: 'Big').save()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:"fix me"
            !Team.findByName('hello')
    }
}
```

When I execute the unit test I get the following runtime error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static abc.Team.findByName() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [hello]
at abc.TeamSpec.test something(TeamSpec.groovy:24)
```

It complains about a dynamic finder that was available in Grails 2.5.x. Can anyone help me to solve that problem? Anyone had such a thing before?

**EDIT**

I created a plain new Grails 3.0.6 and generated a domain class by the task `create-domain-class`. Then I added the three String attributes (name, shortName, image) to the class and wrote a simple assertion `!Team.findByName('A')` but the exception remains.

**EDIT 2**
I still have no clue what I am doing wrong. I reported that issue to the [Grails-Core issue tracker](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9262). Example code can be found [here](https://github.com/saw303/abc)

**EDIT 3**
`@TestFor` does the job but I would like to work with the `HibernateTestMixin` instead of `DomainClassUnitTestMixin` in favour of a H2 in memory database. Therefore I added

```
testCompile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:4.0.5.RELEASE'
```

to my `build.gradle`. But when I add the `HibernateTestMixin` I get the following exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.SimpleMapDatastore] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.getSimpleDatastore(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:76)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:86)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:119)
at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomain(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:118)
at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:84)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:46)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:73)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is officially a bug that will be fixed by the release of Grails 3.0.8

[Link to the bug](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9262)

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine - this example is using grails 3.0.1. http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.1/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains

I'm guessing using @TestFor annotation may do the trick for you. It will set up whatever mixins are needed, based on what you are testing. Here's my working example, which resides at

/src/test/groovy/grails3test/TeamSpec.groovy:

```
package grails3test

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestFor(Team)
class TeamSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
        Team t = new Team(name: 'alphabravo')
        t.save()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:
        Team.findByName('alphabravo') != null
    }
}
```

Comment: This example works. Thank you. I would like to use HibernateTestMixin with the H2 in memory DB. As soon I add the @HibernateTestMixin annotation I get the exception. Is `org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:4.0.5.RELEASE` somehow not compatible with Grails 3.0.x? See above in **EDIT 3**